# Dynamic creation of onclick events on dynamically created elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make a dynamically created navigation in which every element can be clicked and sent somewhere (don't worry about that). Here's my fragment of code:

```
        var navigation = $('<ul></ul>');
        for(a = 0; a < no_of_elements; a++) {
            navigation_content = $('<li></li>').click(function { send_me_to(a) });
            navigation_content.appendTo(navigation);
        }
        navigation.appendTo('.container');
```

Everything was working just fine until I added .click(...) in the 3rd line. I also tried to split it into two lines, like so:

```
            navigation_content = $('<li></li>');
            navigation_content.click(function { send_me_to(a) });
```

...with no results, though. What is the proper way to bind click event to such elements? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Assign `.click` after You `.appendTo`

Comment: I tried the following:

   navigation_content = $('<li></li>');
   navigation_content.appendTo(navigation);
   navigation_content.click(function { alert("I'm working!") });

and Firefox is giving me SyntaxError: missing ( before formal parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if the parentheses after the function keyword are mandatory, but the way you use a in the click handler will not have the result you expect. You could do something like that:

```
navigation_content.click((function(aa) {
    return function() { send_me_to(aa); };
})(a));
```

Answer (score 4):

In the function expression, you're missing the parenthesis `()`:

```
navigation_content = $('<li></li>').click(function() { send_me_to(a) });
//                                                ^^ missing
```

Comment: It seems that it's not possible to mark two answers as the accepted answer, but your help was equally valuable. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
navigation_content.on('click',function(){
  send_me_to(a);
})
```

EDIT : 
Second solution:

```
 navigation_content = $('<li id="li-link-'+a+'" data-id="'+a+'"></li>')
```

after  "navigation.appendTo('.container');" add this code

```
$('li[id^="li-link"]').on('click' , function(){
send_me_to($(this).data('id'));
});
```

cheers.

Comment: This is no different to what the OP has.

Answer (score 0):

***[`jsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/L4C6S/)***

I believe the issue is probably with sending `a`. It is probably only sending the last one since it isn't closed over. There is also a syntax error, the anonymous click function needs `()` after it

```
var navigation = $('<ul></ul>');
for(a = 0; a < no_of_elements; a++) {
 navigation_content = new function(){
  var copya = a;
  return $('<li></li>').click(function() { send_me_to(copya) });
 };
 navigation_content.appendTo(navigation);
}
navigation.appendTo('.container');
```

Comment: send_me_to(a) was written just for illustration, it's not in the code yet and though it cannot give me an error. Currently there's an alert there, like so: alert("I'm working!"), and I still get an error: SyntaxError: missing ( before formal parameters

Comment: @WojciechMaj - There is also a syntax error, see my edit please